# How do I make my low poly rocks look more sharp?

Tags: modeling, scene

### I have been making this scene with big rocks/mountains in the background, but from far away, the rocks look bland, how do I make them look more sharp and interesting?

For some reason, the rocks in the background don't look too great from far away, however, when you get close, you can see the detail that I made.
Any ideas on how to make them look good even from far away?

The last picture is now an updated version, where the tips in the comments were used.

[image: These are the rocks from far away.]

[image: These are the rocks from up-close.]

[image: This is an updated picture.]

Comment: have you tried a different lighting? the current one make your objects look a bit flat, maybe it's because of your world color?

Comment: yea, that's what I would think is the lighting is kind of flat right now. Maybe make your background lighting darker.

Comment: Darker background lighting doesn't seem to work, I have the background color and world lighting separated though, so that might be affecting the result

Comment: Agreed.. you need a key light (Sun?) from _one direction_ to play a bigger part, relative to the world/ambient light, or any other soft / fill light you might be using. Temporarily hide lights, so you can see their effect one at a time.

Comment: With a sun added I got some good detail on the z axis, but the creases on the x axis still aren't too detailed.

Comment: And then blender crashes... yay

Comment: Can you update/add the images to the post so we can see the current level of improvement?

Comment: Yes  (This is just filling so I can actually post this)